# Evaluate $\int_0^{\sqrt{5}} \sqrt{4x^4 + 16 x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{5}} \sqrt{4x^4 + 16 x^2} dx$$

The square root really got me confused here. I've tried using the standard trick with $x = x + \sqrt{x^2+4}$ but failed. That might still be the best approach.

What's the best way to solve this and how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT : Since $x\ge 0,$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt 5}\sqrt{(2x)^2(x^2+4)}\ dx=\int_{0}^{\sqrt 5}\color{red}{2x}\sqrt{x^2+4}\ \color{red}{dx}.$$
Then, setting $x^2+4=u$ gives you $\color{red}{2xdx}=du.$

Answer (score 4):

For real $x,$
$$\sqrt{4x^4+16x^2}=\sqrt{4x^2(x^2+4)}=2|x|\sqrt{x^2+4}$$

As $x\ge0,$ $$\sqrt{4x^4+16x^2}=2x\sqrt{x^2+4}$$

Set $x^2+4=u$ or $x^2+4=u^2$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, What are the better alternatives?

Comment: Sorry lab, I'm sleepy. +1.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey, Wish you really had one better alternative, I'm glad to accept

Answer (score 2):

Write the integrand as $ 2 x \sqrt{x^2 + 4}$. Now notice the substitution $x^2 = u$. I'm sure you can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
\begin{align}
\int^\sqrt{5}_0\sqrt{4x^4+16x^2} \ dx
&=2\int^{\sqrt{5}}_0 x\sqrt{x^2+4} \ dx \\
\end{align}
Now let $x=2\tan{u}$, then $dx=2\sec^2{u} \ du$.
\begin{align}
2\int^{\sqrt{5}}_0 x\sqrt{x^2+4} \ dx 
&=8\int^{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}_0 \tan{u}\sec^3{u} \ du\\
\end{align}
Use the substitution $y=\sec{u} \implies dy=\sec{u}\tan{u} \ du$. You should be able to take it from here.